# UIActivityIndicatorView invisible in google maps sdk mapView

Tags: uiactivityindicatorview, google-maps-sdk-ios, invisible

I've been trying to add an UIActivityIndicatorView to the google map sdk based view that will animate while the pins are loading.  The map loads and the pins drop, but the activity indicator is masked, hidden or not included.  I've been successful with this same behavior using the iOS based map implementation, but would prefer to do this in google maps if possible.  Could this have anything to do with the threading behavior?
Thanks, 
res

```
//view's .h
//this was created from dragging from the view to the .h file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

//view's .m
@synthesize activityIndicator;

...
//viewDidLoad calls a function that kicks off the animation
self.view = mapView;
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];


//later after the final pin is dropped the following is called
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard code from google to add the map view, you may be overwriting the root view, which would have the activity indicator on it.

Can you post the code you use to add the map view?